# Displays randomly stopped working, will not come back after multiple reboots and trying tons of tests

Tags: memory, graphics-card, display, multiple-monitors, motherboard

I've been at it for the last three hours trying to figure this out.

[This is my PC](https://www.ibuypower.com/store/gaming-rdy-smrrg201) I got it back in early December.

- List item
- AMD Ryzen 5 3600 CPU
- ASUS PRIME B450M-A MB
- MSI VENTUS GeForce GTX 1660 Ti 6GB GPU
- 16GB DDR4-3000MHz ADATA RAM
- 500GB WD SSD + 1TB Crucial NVMe M.2 SSD
- I use an LG TV w/ an hdmi as my main monitor and an Acer S230HL w/ a dvi to displayport adapter.

I was watching a video on YouTube when both screens froze, then went black. I waited about 30 seconds and then powered the computer off. When I booted it back up it was still giving no signal to either display so I shut it off and tried again with only the TV, still no signal. I then swapped cables and tried both individually, got nothing so I tried two different monitors and still got nothing. Four different displays with four different cables, nothing.

Then I pulled out the GPU and swapped it with an old Ati Radeon 5750 I had lying around, still nothing. So since the GPU isn't the problem, I thought it could be RAM. I pulled out each stick tested them individually and together with every slot combination possible, still nothing. All the pins in both pcie slots are fine.

My CPU doesn't have integrated graphics so I can't use that. When I booted it, I tried to guess which account I was logging into and use that password, but it didn't have any response. My keyboard and mouse lights only turn on when I'm signed in, so I knew I wasn't getting logged into any account the fact the lights were still off. I tried several USB slots and used 3 other sets of M&Ks, and tried to get it to boot in safe mode but met the same results. Not even Caps or Num lock will go on.

I pulled the ssd that windows is on, thinking maybe windows could be the problem, but nothing showed up still. I don't know if anything would, but I thought I'd at least see the BIOS.

I'm not really sure what else to do now. I've removed and swapped out everything but the CPU and Motherboard, and it could be that both sticks of Ram are bad, but I'll be able to test that tomorrow. I just don't know. There's lights on the motherboard, one line and one next to the Pcie port my gpu is in, but all I can find on them is that they're for aesthetic purposes, not diagnostic.

Finally, I removed the battery from the motherboard and left it out for 10 minutes, then reinserted it, to restore the BIOS to its defaults. Nothing.

Please help. I need this for work and their are sensitive files on it that make me hesitant to send it out to get fixed. I'm going to call the IBP support when they open.

TL;DR: I tried a bunch of stuff, potentially ruled out it being GPU, RAM, BIOS, storage, OS, displays, and display cables. I don't know what else to do.

Comment: Good testing, but I miss a few things which you can do: 1. Test both screens with another video source. (e.g. someone's laptop). I am assuming they both will work since both dying at the same time is pretty unlikely. At least as long as they are plugged in. (sanity check; not two different outlets of those in a power strip with an on/off switch?).  2) Should you send in for repair remove the drive. That way you still have all the data. A repaired PC should boot just fine to firmware (UEFI these days or BIOS on very old computers) without the need to go to windows.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I tested both monitors with my PS4 and they worked fine. It's looking like I'll have to send it in, but good point that I can remove the SSDs. I think the weirdest thing is that nothing on the motherboard is being recognized. USB and audio ports are not showing up at all. But my RGB fans work fine. Not even the Ethernet port's lights work. Thanks again.